# How do I find out what AWS resource(s) is using a specific security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just reinstated an old AWS account and I'm looking to delete all the security groups and start fresh. I don't have any EC2 instances and I deleted the VPC as well and I'm still left with one security group that I can't delete. Is there any way to find out what AWS services are in use? Or which service is using this security group?

The group shows up both in the ec2 security group area and the vpc security group area, this is the error when I try to delete it in the latter.

> We could not delete the following security group (sg-60add108)
>   The 'default' security group is reserved, and cannot be deleted by a user. If creating a security group, specify a different name. (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroup.Reserved; Request ID: e6aefcf6-878f-4275-9d67-ceecc1a432ea)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about the default security group, which cannot be deleted. You can learn more about it from the following link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#default-security-group

Comment: There's a bit of inconsistency here. I understand that the VPC needs a default sec group.  But I deleted the VPC for this specific region. All my other regions with VPC's have only one sec group total. This region has no ec2 instances or vpc so I don't understand why I have a sec group.

Comment: I just created a VPC to see if it would create a total of 2 Sec Groups and it did, and I tried to delete the previous one and it failed again...

Comment: Just confirmed using the VPC sec group panel theres a drop down to filter between VPC sec groups and EC2 sec groups that the one I'm trying to delete is EC2 but I don't have any instances...

Comment: Have you read the link that I have mentioned in my reply?